# Why doesn't my program print anything after all the commands?

Tags: c, string, while-loop, command, strtok

[image]

The problem is to parse a series of commands that instruct a robot arm on how to manipulate blocks that lie on a flat table. Initially, there are n blocks on the table (numbered from 0 to n − 1) with block bi adjacent to block bi+1 for all 0 ≤ i < n − 1 as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

The valid commands for the robot arm that manipulates blocks are:

• move a onto b

where a and b are block numbers, puts block a onto block b after returning any blocks that are stacked on top of blocks a and b to their initial positions.

• move a over b

puts block a onto the top of the stack containing block b, after returning any blocks that are stacked on top of block a to their initial positions.

• pile a onto b

moves the pile of blocks consisting of block a, and any blocks that are stacked above block a, onto block b. All blocks on top of block b are moved to their initial positions prior to the pile taking place. The blocks stacked above block a retain their order when moved.

• pile a over b

puts the pile of blocks consisting of block a, and any blocks that are stacked above block a, onto the top of the stack containing block b. The blocks stacked above block a retain their original order when moved.

• quit

terminates manipulations in the block world. Any command in which a = b or in which a and b are in the same stack of blocks is an illegal command. All illegal commands should be ignored and should have no effect on the configuration of blocks.

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void back(int arr[]) {

}
int main() {
    int noi = 0;
    printf("please input n:");
    int n;
    scanf(" %d", & n);
    int arr[n][n];
    //this for storing their position
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = -1;
        }
        arr[i][0] = i;
    }
    //empty as -1
    char str1[5], str2[5], cmd[20]; //cmd is the complete line which will be spilt
    int s, d; //source & destination
    char st[2], dt[2]; //char variable of int s and d
    char * tk; //a pointer for strtok
    int quit = 0;

    while (1) {
        s = -1;
        d = -1;
        while (!(s >= 0 && s < n && d >= 0 && d < n)) {
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin);
            tk = strtok(cmd, " ");
            if (strcmp(tk, "quit") == 0) {
                quit = 1;
                break;
            } else {
                strcpy(str1, tk);
                tk = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(st, tk);
                s = atoi(st);
                tk = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(str2, tk);
                tk = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(dt, tk);
                d = atoi(dt);
            }
        }
        if (quit == 1) {
            break;
        }
        //finally doing the commands
        if (strcmp(str1, "move") == 0) {
            if (strcmp(str2, "onto") == 0) {
                //empty s
                for (i = 0; i < n && arr[s][i] != -1; i++) {
                    arr[arr[s][i]][0] = arr[s][i];
                    arr[s][i] = -1;
                }
                //empty d
                for (i = 0; i < n && arr[d][i] != -1; i++) {
                    arr[arr[d][i]][0] = arr[d][i];
                    arr[d][i] = -1;
                }
                //now move s to d
                i = 1;
                arr[d][i] = arr[s][0];
                arr[s][0] = -1;
            } else if (strcmp(str2, "over") == 0) {

                //empty s
                for (i = 0; i < n && arr[s][i] != -1; i++) {
                    arr[arr[s][i]][0] = arr[s][i];
                    arr[s][i] = -1;
                }
                //move s to d
                i = 1;
                while (arr[d][i] != -1) {
                    i++;
                }
                arr[d][i] = arr[s][0];
                arr[s][0] = -1;
            }
        } else if (strcmp(str1, "pile") == 0) {
            if (strcmp(str2, "onto")) {
                //empty d
                for (i = 0; i < n && arr[d][i] != -1; i++) {
                    arr[arr[d][i]][0] = arr[d][i];
                    arr[d][i] = -1;
                }
                //pile s to d
                //find empty of d
                i = 1;
                while (arr[d][i] != -1) {
                    i++;
                }
                //find end(empty) of s and store in j
                j = 0;
                while (arr[s][j] != -1) {
                    j++;
                }
                //piling
                int tj = 0; //for iterating in s
                while (j - 1 >= 0) {
                    arr[d][i] = arr[s][tj];
                    arr[s][tj] = -1;
                    j--;
                    tj++;
                    i++;
                }
            } else if (strcmp(str2, "over")) {
                //pile s to d
                //find empty of d
                i = 1;
                while (arr[d][i] != -1) {
                    i++;
                }
                //find end(empty) of s and store in j
                j = 0;
                while (arr[s][j] != -1) {
                    j++;
                }
                //piling
                int tj = 0; //for iterating in s
                while (j - 1 >= 0) {
                    arr[d][i] = arr[s][tj];
                    arr[s][tj] = -1;
                    j--;
                    tj++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //print results
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d:", i);
        for (j = 0; j < n && arr[i][j] != -1; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to run the code in a debugger. Add some breakpoints and step through the code to see what is happening and make sure it agrees with what you think should be happening. If I had to guess `if(strcmp(tk,"quit")==0){` is probably never true because you don't deal with the `\n` that `fgets` leaves at the end of the string.

Comment: The problem is that fgets also reads the newline at the end of the input.  So the input will NEVER match "quit" - so either you need to remove the newline or expect it to be there.  Here is an example where I remove it: https://onlinegdb.com/SklYn9c0X_